# how to fix issues while setting environment variable?

Tags: python, batch-file

I am using a command file to set an environment variable BUILD_VER,for some reason it doesnt seem to take affect,
any idea what could be wrong and how to fix it?

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM ADDING LOGIC TO GET THE BUILD_VER FROM NETWORK LOCATION
REM set $NetPath="Z:\Build_ver\build_ver.txt" 
set $NetPath="\\Network\files\Build_ver\build_ver.txt"
set /p version=<\\Network\files\Build_ver\build_ver.txt
set BUILD_VER=%version%
echo %BUILD_VER%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setlocal`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx) makes your changes to disappear as soon as the .bat file finishes.

Comment: A reference link would be nice.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx Common knowledge I suppose.

Comment: Clearly not, if the OP had to ask the question. Just trying to help improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the variable first before redirecting it to a text file ... e.g 
something like this.......

```
@echo off 
set $netpath=your path here
echo %$netpath%>myfile.txt
```

Hope this helps.